# Understanding OCaml Lwt.return_unit

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to understand [this line](https://github.com/mirage/mirage-tcpip/blob/master/examples/ping/ping.ml#L104):

```
Icmpv4_socket.connect ()
    >>= fun stack ->
```

It is defined [here](https://github.com/mirage/mirage-tcpip/blob/master/src/stack-unix/icmpv4_socket.ml#L15):

```
let connect () = Lwt.return_unit
```

`Icmpv4_socket.connect ()` resolves to  `Lwt.return_unit` so I understand this line as resolving to a fulfilled Lwt promite. Where the value that is filled is a function with paremeter `stack`. If I understood correctly, why is this function inside a promise useful? Who calls it with the  `stack` parameter? Context: it's all inside an Lwt run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lwt.return_unit` is a ready-made value of type `unit Lwt.t`, in other words, a promise which does absolutely nothing. Both `Icmpv4_socket.connect` and `disconnect` are defined to evaluate to this do-nothing value, which means they are explicitly doing nothing.

> Where the value that is filled is a function with paremeter `stack`

Actually, the value that is filled is `stack` itself. The reason the code is written like this:

```
Icmpv4_socket.connect ()
>>= fun stack ->
```

...is to *force* the `connect` function to run first, fulfill its promise, *and then* run the contents of the function `fun stack -> ...` to fulfill *its* promise. That's done by using the `>>=` (called 'bind') operator. There's an excellent tutorial by the Mirage folks about Lwt's lightweight threading model, the 'bind' operator, and such topics: https://mirage.io/wiki/tutorial-lwt

You may be asking, why does the `connect` function have to run if it actually does nothing at all? That's because this implementation detail is not exposed to calling code. Such code only sees the [signature](https://github.com/mirage/mirage-tcpip/blob/29a95d4bfba14a4ffaf473cdb2ee7b442b8759ec/src/stack-unix/icmpv4_socket.mli) which looks like:

```
val connect : unit -> t Lwt.t
```

So all we know is that we need to call `connect ()`, get an `Lwt` thread that gives us some value (the `stack`), and continue from there.

Comment: Note that no *promise* ever *does* anything. Promises are just data cells that can have lists of callbacks attached to them. It is functions that do something. Some functions return promises. Also, there is no notion of threads in Lwt (despite old usage of such terms appearing in many places, including parts of the Lwt manual that haven't been updated in too long). See https://ocsigen.org/lwt/5.2.0/api/Lwt. Also, promises can't be forced (there is nothing to force, and the function already ran, any operation is in progress).

Comment: Thank you, much clearer now. Just one thing: if `Icmpv4_socket.connect ()
>>= fun stack ->` was all in one line, it'd have a different result?

Comment: Thanks @antron for clarifying.

Comment: @LucasZanella nope, it would have the same result. OCaml is whitespace- and indentation-insensitive.